# How to convert non-english char in string to lowercase without printing �?

Tags: c++

When i'm trying to convert string to lowercase, non-english characters are converted to �

Take string from first file, convert it to lowercase and print in second file.

Let's say first line would be:

1.`Testing Strings For Conversion`

2.`Test Des Chaînes Pour La Conversion` (French google translate)

```
main(){
    ifstream old_file;
    ofstream new_file;
    string str;

    old_file.open("first.txt");
    new_file.open("second.txt");

    getline(old_file, str);
    transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::tolower);
    new_file << str;

    old_file.close()
    new_file.close()
}
```

Result will be:

1.`testing strings for conversion`

2.`test des cha�nes pour la conversion`

Input file encoding "UTF-8 with BOM"

Comment: use this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/tolower (but its complicated to get this always right)

Comment: I'd use the [ICU](https://icu.unicode.org/design/cpp) library.

Comment: Added encoding info "UTF-8 with BOM"

Comment: With your current setup which uses `C-locale` there are no characters other then ASCII. You need to select some encoding so standard library can understand how to handle none ASCII characters.

Comment: @m2j `tolower` won't work as it only operates on single characters so will fail with multi-byte encodings like utf-8. Nothing in the standard library will help you here, you'll need an external unicode library

Comment: Death to "UTF-8 with BOM". BOMs have no place in UTF-8 text.

Comment: [UTF-8 Everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/), no BOMs!

Comment: The only simple and reliable way to do it is use wide characters: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b2e337f04ea1de9b https://godbolt.org/z/Wvv3TYzv9 Note that setting imbue on stream defines its encoding, so you need to: `std::wifstream f{"your_file.txt"}; f.imbue(std::locale{"C.UTF-8"});`. Remember to set global locale.